# Проверка всех CheckBox в C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, checkbox

Можно ли объединить все чекбоксы на форме в массив и проверить их с помощью цикла?

Comment: проверить на что? что вы хотите с чекбокса поместить в массив?

Comment: Проверить состояние (checked = true/false)

Comment: Обходите рекурсивно все элементы и обрабатывайте так, как Вам нужно.

Comment: я думаю можно))

Comment: @Yaroslav c чего вы взяли что это винформ?

Comment: @SeeSharp, а я и не знал, просто предположил.

Comment: @Yaroslav я могу предположить что он регистрационное окно делает? Если да, то никаких более вопросов.

Comment: @ SeeSharp, вопрос не понятен,  кто что делает.

Comment: @SeeSharp, может и так

Comment: @Yaroslav я думаю стоит или убрать метку с `winform` или добавить тогда метку `wpf`

Comment: @SeeSharp, конечно добавить.

Answer (score 2):

Ну раз это все же WinForms, то банально взять все контролы одного типа:

```
var checkBoxes = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
```

Где [Controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls) - свойство самой формы. [OfType](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype) - LINQ фильтрация коллекции по типу.

Результатом будет коллекция, которая содержит в себе все `CheckBox` текущего окна. А дальше делайте что вашей душе угодно, хоть циклом гоняйте, хоть меняйте значения определенным элементам.

Comment: что то здесь не так.

Comment: @Yaroslav И что же?

Comment: это код явно не будет работать

Comment: @Yaroslav А вы проверяли? Я - [да](https://evgeniy-z.ru/wfresult.gif). Или вам лишь бы сказать и минус влепить? Хорошо, тогда пойдем по вашему пути - сейчас заминусую ваш ответ, где вы создаете тупо в коде элементы, не беря их с формы, когда вопрос `объединить все чекбоксы на форме в массив`. Ответ SeeSharp тоже в минус, ибо у него тот же почти вариант, что и у меня, только он возьмет все элементы (кнопки, картинки и др.) и попытается загнать это в лист чекбоксов, получится ли? Не думаю. Я правильно все понял?

Comment: я Вас понял, но у меня почему то ошибка:
Ошибка CS0103 Имя "Controls" не существует в текущем контексте.

Comment: @Yaroslav Ну значит вы что то делаете не так, а не способ не верный. [Controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=netframework-4.7.2) это свойство, которое есть у самого WinForm. Попробуйте `this.Controls`, я не знаю вашу структуру, у меня пустой проект и сами видите, все работает как и должно. Расстроили вы меня однако, расстроили...

Comment: допишите что то в ответ, тогда у меня получится снять -1, я понял в чем прикол, получается что нет инициализированной формы и оно и за этого ругается.

Comment: var control = new Control();
            var chekBox = control.Controls
                                 .OfType<CheckBox>()
                                 .Where(x => x.Checked)
                                 .Select(x => x);

Comment: @Yaroslav На будущее, прежде чем минусовать - старайтесь разобраться и уж затем делать выводы. Ибо у меня сейчас такое впечатление, что вы специально решили взять и испортить мне репутацию, не проверяя даже ответы других людей. Ибо если бы вы проверили ответ SeeSharp, то напоролись бы на те же грабли!

Comment: ok) больше не буду.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо что указали на мою ошибку в коде. Не сделал проверку `is CheckBox`.

Answer (score 0):

### Для WinForms

```
List<CheckBox> allBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();

foreach(var checkBox in this.Controls){
    if (checkBox is CheckBox)
        allBoxes.Add(checkBox);
    //Или работать вот тут со свойством Checked
}
```

### Для WPF

```
foreach( FrameworkElement checkBox in grid.Children )
{
   if (checkBox is CheckBox)
   {
       //Опять работаем с каждым. Можно сначала в массив, а потом по индексу
   }
}
```